# Monitoring datas with HighChart using .net6 and javaScript

Tags: javascript, signalr, .net-6.0, signalr-hub

I have a BackgroundService class that is load 60 point of data at first load then add a point every minute to chart.I have used SignalR with HighChart in .Net6,the problem is that adding point in javascript class does not work.I want to add a point with it's data's at the end of the chart then shift it .
this is backgroundService Class:

```
 public class TxnRespHistoryBackgroundCaller : BackgroundService
{

    public ITxnRespHistoryRepository Repository { get; }
    public IHubContext<MonitoringHub> HubContext { get; }
    private bool isFirstCall = true;

    public TxnRespHistoryBackgroundCaller(ITxnRespHistoryRepository repository, IHubContext<MonitoringHub> hubContext)
    {
        Repository = repository;
        HubContext = hubContext;

    }
    private static List<string> FailResps
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {

                return new List<string>() { "3", "92", "91", "96", "80", "84" };

            }
            catch
            {
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
            if (isFirstCall == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var datasets = new List<dynamic>();

                    DateTime FinishTime = DateTime.Now;

                    try
                    {
                        FinishTime = Repository.GetMax(TxnRespHistory.Columns.EndTime);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            FinishTime = Repository.GetServerTime();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            FinishTime = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }

                    var yesterdayalltxn = await Repository.GetTxnHisByResp(59, TransactionType.Yesterday, FinishTime, FailResps);
                    var failtxn = await Repository.GetTxnHisByResp(59, TransactionType.fail, FinishTime, FailResps);
                    var alltxn = await Repository.GetTxnHisByResp(59, TransactionType.All, FinishTime, FailResps);
                    var suctxn = await Repository.GetTxnHisByResp(59, TransactionType.successful, FinishTime, FailResps);


                    datasets.Add(new
                    {
                        data = suctxn.Value,
                        label = "Success",
                        Key = "Success",
                        color = "#308014"
                    });

                    datasets.Add(new
                    {
                        data = failtxn.Value,
                        label = "UnSuccess",
                        Key = "Fail",
                        color = "#ff0000"
                    });

                    datasets.Add(new
                    {
                        data = alltxn.Value,
                        label = "Total",
                        Key = "Total",
                        color = "#7094db"
                    });

                    datasets.Add(new
                    {
                        data = yesterdayalltxn.Value,
                        label = "Yesterday",
                        Key = "Yesterday",
                        color = "#b3b3b3"
                    });

                    var result = new
                    {
                        success = true,
                        labels = alltxn.Key,
                        datasets = datasets
                    };

                    await HubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("populatetxns", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
                    isFirstCall = false;
                    
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                }
            }
            else
            {

                    try
                    {
                        var newtxn = Repository.AddtxnHisByResp(FailResps);


                        var result = new
                        {
                            labels = newtxn.Key,
                            datasets = newtxn.Value
                        };

                        await HubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("populatetxns", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
           


        });
    }





}
```

and this is javaScript Code :

```js
let txnresphisbycha = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    let isFirstCallSuccess = false;
    
    var connection = new signalR
        .HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/monitoringHub").build();

    connection.start().then(() => console.log("hubconnected")).catch(() => console.log(error));//establish connection
    
   
    connection.on("populatetxns", (result) => {
        if (isFirstCallSuccess == false)
            getChartData(JSON.parse(result));
        else
            addChartData(JSON.parse(result));
        });

    

    function getChartData(result) {

        var dataSets = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < result.datasets.length; i++) {
            var entity = {};
            entity.name = result.datasets[i].label;
            entity.data = result.datasets[i].data;
            entity.color = result.datasets[i].color;
            entity.type = 'area';
            dataSets.push(entity);

        }
     
        txnresphisbycha = Highcharts.chart('txnhisbyrespcha', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                alignTicks: false,
                height: (10 / 22 * 100) + '%',// set ratio
                
            },

            
            title: {
                text: 'Total Transaction Chart'
                
            },
            credits: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                rtl: true,
                y: 25,
                margin: 0,
                shadow: true,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                itemStyle: {
                    cursor: "pointer",                  
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                rtl: true,
                split: false,
                shared: true,
                xDateFormat: '%H:%M',
                useHTML: true,
                style: {
                    
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    rtl: true,
                },
                distance: 30,
                padding: 5,
                headerFormat: '<span>{point.key}</span><br/>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                zoomEnabled: true,
                categories: result.labels,
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval: 1,
                labels: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    step: 1,
                    rotation: 55,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '11px'
                        
                    },
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Quantity",
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '15px',
                        
                    },
                },
                opposite: false,
                endOnTick: true,
                showLastLabel: true,
                
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '15px',
                        
                    },
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -7,
                    y: 5,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointRange: 1 * 60 * 1000,
                    fillOpacity: 0.2,
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'circle'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: dataSets,
            navigator: {
                enabled: true
            }
        });
        
        isFirstCallSuccess = true;
        
    }
 
    function addChartData(result) {
        if (!isFirstCallSuccess) return;
        debugger;
        if (txnresphisbycha.series[0].data[txnresphisbycha.series[0].data.length - 1].category != result.labels[0]) {

            txnresphisbycha.series[0].addPoint({
                x: result.labels[0],
                function() {
                    for (var i in result.datasets) {
                     
                    y: result.datasets[i]

                    }
                },
                dataLables: { enabled: true }
            },
            true
           ,true)

            
            txnresphisbycha.update();
        }

    }

})
```